# Cropped image displayed with a weird 1px black border

Tags: javascript, jspdf, cropperjs, cropper

***EDIT:*** I've made a [video](https://youtu.be/DKwlD2-lw8M) showing the current issue. Recorded it on an old macbook so it took a while haha. Anyway, In the video you can see me uploading an image, cropping it and generating a pdf with it. The preview does not have a black border whatsoever, the pdf DOES have a black border. Hope this helped.

So I got a webapplication that lets the user upload a profile picture and later generate a pdf with the profile picture. The problem is that I would like to have the profile picture displayed with rounded corners / in a circle.

I am using `jspdf` to generate the pdf. With that library I can add an image with the `addImage` method, that takes a base64 encoded DataUrl. Unfortunately, there isn't a native method to display the image with rounded corners / in a circle, so I decided to let the user crop their image before encoding the url to base64. That's when the weird behavior starts... If the cropped image is displayed in a `img` tag, it's all good, a nice circle profile picture is displayed. When that dataUrl is used to generate a pdf, for some reason a 1px black border is generated around the image... If I inspect the dataurl in the browser or with a online base64 previewer, no black border is visible, only when it gets generated as a pdf...

For demonstration purposes I made a [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/vue-template-p9w2t). Images with a white background show the problem best. For example, use this image: [profilepicture](https://gyazo.com/e32a2e9c70df6ba3141eb8193dcd0179)

This method is most likely what is causing the problem (I took this one directly from the cropperjs examples on github):

```
function getRoundedCanvas(sourceCanvas) {
        var canvas = document.createElement("canvas");
        var context = canvas.getContext("2d");
        var width = sourceCanvas.width;
        var height = sourceCanvas.height;
        canvas.width = width;
        canvas.height = height;
        context.imageSmoothingEnabled = true;
        context.drawImage(sourceCanvas, 0, 0, width, height);
        context.globalCompositeOperation = "destination-in";
        context.beginPath();
        context.arc(
            width / 2,
            height / 2,
            Math.min(width, height) / 2,
            0,
            2 * Math.PI,
            true
        );
        context.fill();
        return canvas;
    }
```

This method is used in the `crop` method like this: `roundedCanvas = getRoundedCanvas(croppedCanvas);` If I take out that method and just use `roundedCanvas = croppedCanvas;` the image gets cropped to a square and is displayed without the black borders.

I have no idea how I can resolve this issue, and if it is even possible to resolve. Any help in the right direction is very much appreciated. Even alternative methods to display rounded / circle images on a pdf are welcome (I already tried `html2canvas` and that didn't work).

Comment: Can't repro neither on FF nor on Chrome. No black border whatsoever for me.

Comment: Hi @Kaiido , I've made a [video](https://youtu.be/DKwlD2-lw8M) showing the current issue. Recorded it on an old macbook so it took a while haha. Anyway, In the video you can see me uploading an image, cropping it and generating a pdf with it. The preview does not have a black border whatsoever, the pdf DOES have a black border. Hope this helped.

Comment: I have the same issue ,did you found a solution for it ?

Comment: @mohamednageh It was a long time ago, but I believe eventually I just used jspdf to draw a white ellipse around the image to sort of 'hide' the black border. Kinda hacky but I did not found a solid solution. I don't know your use case but you're much better of just using something like `Puppeteer` to convert html to pdf.

Comment: Okay, thanks @Reinier68